# Excel WebQuery malformed after Office update (Version 1705)

Tags: asp.net, windows, excel, excel-web-query, vba

The excel workbook (populated by webqueries using VBA) , which , I have been using for more than a year now has suddenly lost many formatting and some data.

Upon debugging, I find that when the HTML has a  tag, the data is not saved to Excel anymore. I removed the  tag in the HTML by replacing  with  and it works. However, other aspects of the webquery like .AdjustColumnWidth = False are being ignored.

Any idea on fixes if any?

I am using Windows 7, Office 365 Excel. The file works absolutely fine on machines that did not receive a Office update recently.

Comment: What happens with existing webqueries?

Comment: I have now found the cause is an office update (1705) and not a windows update. The existing web queries -> the .adjustcolumnwidth param is completely ignored. Column widths get adjusted no matter what, and if the html contains <span> the text does not get saved the the DB. Also, border formatting of tables are lost. <br/> is not recognized and Excel does not create a new empty row for the br tag anymore.

Comment: Good catch. I think it is a good idea to report this problem at this page: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel?auth=1 it is where MSFT support looks for bug reports by customers.

Comment: I have reported the problem to the Excel team, they will look into this.

Comment: Thanks, I have, as well. Hopefully there will be some respose from Microsoft.